# Remove big.mark from one variable in {gtsummary}?

Tags: gtsummary

I understand there is a way to alter big.mark for an entire theme but I wonder if there is a way to remove it for a single variable? I am displaying summary statistics for year of birth and ideally it would not have a comma (e.g., "1988" is better than "1,988").

Many thanks,
Doron

Comment: You can use the `tbl_summary(digits=)` argument, e.g. `tbl_summary(digits = year ~ list(as.character))`

Comment: Thanks for the help! That suggestion worked but introduced many decimal points so was not usable. I ended up using child_yob ~ purrr::partial(style_number, digits = 0, big.mark = "") which worked perfectly!